# Sketch: import SVGs with filters

Tags: svg, sketch-app

I have an SVG with a filter tag that several elements are using. How do I get Sketch to recognize it?

This is a simpler SVG, but it conveys my point:

```
<svg width="230" height="120">
  <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
  </filter>

  <circle cx="60"  cy="60" r="50" fill="green" />

  <circle cx="170" cy="60" r="50" fill="green" filter="url(#blurMe)" />
</svg>
```

*(example comes from MDN article on* <filter>*)*

When viewed in a browser, this looks like this:

[image: correct]

But what Sketch gives me is this:

[image: sketch-app]

How do I get Sketch to include the filter? Or if it's impossible, is there a workaround where I can apply the filter?

Comment: My filter was basically adding a shadow, so the workaround I used was to manually add a shadow to each element in Sketch. I'm hoping there's a better answer.

Comment: I don't think Sketch understands SVG filters. Adobe Illustrator should be able to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using Inkscape(dot)org?  It's free, and Open Source, and it displays that filter properly.

Comment: @AAGD The ridiculous this is that Sketch _generates_ SVG filters, but doesn't understand them when they're imported.

Comment: @BillyKerr I like Inkscape (although it seems to misbehave on my Mac), but my boss is using Sketch, soooooooo ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Have you perhaps thought about using Inkscape under a virtual Linux machine on your mac?  That might help with instability issues with Inkscape on mac.  Also, I use Inkscape with Windows - it's pretty stable there too.